# Lambda expression replace why can I use "%" operator and not the ">" operator

Tags: c#, lambda

```
  return x%2 != 0; // Return true if x is odd. => ok


  return x>0 == 1; // Return true if x > 0 => this won't work
```

Can someone tell me why the second line isn't working ? Why can't I use the `">"`, `"="`, `"<"` ... operators ?

Comment: Wow...@RobertHarvey your comment just rippled through every answer!

Comment: In my defense I was editing and adding while he commented that! :P

Comment: Your comment does not match the code on the first line. `return x % 2 == 1;` does not return whether x is odd or not; it returns whether x is *both positive and odd*. The correct code is `return x % 2 != 0;`

Comment: Thank you @EricLippert you're absolutely right, edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `x > 0` is a boolean, not an int.

You could simplify this by using `return x > 0;`

Answer (score 1):

`>`  is comparison operator which returns a boolean value.

Simply

```
public bool FooBar(int x)
{
    return x > 0;
}
```

Of all the operators you asked, all will work except `=`. It is an assignment operator in C#. So you can't do

```
return x = 1;
```

but you can do

```
return x == 1;
```

OR

```
return x < 1;
```